# Android- empty space at top of list view

Tags: android, xml, listview, listadapter

I currently have a `tabview` with a `listview` inside. I only have three items in the `listview` and for some reason there is a bunch of white space at top. That is, the first item doesn't start at the top but rather in the middle. Any ideas? Also, i'm thinking that I am using the wrong layout. anything better than a `listview` if i only need to display three items? Thanks.

Code:

```
// Data to put in the ListAdapter
    private String[] sdrPlaylistNames = new String[]{ "More Playlists...","Dubstep", "House"};


    Intent playbackServiceIntentDUB, playbackServiceIntentHOUSE;

    //alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlists_layout);
        //fill the screen with the list adapter
        playlistFillData();

        playbackServiceIntentDUB = new Intent(this, DUBAudioService.class); 
        playbackServiceIntentHOUSE = new Intent(this, HOUSEAudioService.class);     

    }

    public void playlistFillData() {
        //create and set up the Array adapter for the list view
        ArrayAdapter<?> sdrListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, R.layout.list_item, sdrPlaylistNames);
        setListAdapter(sdrListAdapter);
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selectP" android:stackFromBottom="false">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Select A Playlist Above"
        android:textColor="#FF3300"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to make the Relative layout width and height as fill_parent and add requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I missed your real problem in my previous answer.

Simply set `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to your list view as

```
<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selectP" android:stackFromBottom="false">
    </ListView>
```

Hope this time I am clear..

Answer (score 1):

If you **want to display only three items** then I think you have to use `TableLayout`.

[Android - Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set your list view to `AlignParentTop = true`